# Can one function have multiple names?

Tags: python, function

I'm developing a bot on Python (2.7, 3.4). I defined a about 30+ dynamic functions which to be used based on bot commands. While development, since not all functions are done, I have to define for them an empty functions (if I not define then code won't run) like this:

```
def c_about():
    return
def c_events():
    return
def c_currentlocation():
    return
```

etc. many dummy functions.

**Question:**
*it is somehow possible in Python to define same function but with multiple names?*
Something like this:

```
def c_about(), c_events(), c_currentlocation():
    return
```

Comment: Alternatively you can define a funtion mapping dictionary: `cmd = {'about': c_about, ...}`. This allow you to decouple command and function names, organize your functions over classes and packages and do something like `cmds.get('mycommand', dummy_function)` which will return the dummy if a function does not exist (yet).

Comment: There are no marks for coding style during development.
If you need to share your code with others before it is finished, then put a comment above those methods to inform others that they are placeholder functions for code to be developed later.

If you just want random function names to return nothing by default when they are not previously defined... python can do that... so ask that question if you want to make an object that will automatically respond to unnamed method calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions do not intern in Python (i.e., automatically share [multiple references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to the same immutable object), but can share the same name:

```
>>> def a(): pass
... 
>>> a
<function a at 0x101c892a8>
>>> def b(): pass
... 
>>> b
<function b at 0x101c89320>
>>> c=a
>>> c
<function a at 0x101c892a8>  # note the physical address is the same as 'a'
```

So clearly you can do:

```
>>> c=d=e=f=g=a
>>> e
<function a at 0x101c892a8>
```

For the case of functions not yet defined, you can use a `try/catch` block by catching either a `NameError`:

```
def default():
    print "default called"

try:
    not_defined()
except NameError:
    default()
```

Or use a dict of funcs and catch the `KeyError`:

```
funcs={"default": default}

try:
    funcs['not_defined']()
except KeyError:
    funcs['default']()
```

Or, you can do `funcs.get(not_defined, default)()` if you prefer that syntax with a dict of funcs.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it's perfectly possible since defined functions are stored in variables like everything else.

```
def foo():
    pass

baz = bar = foo
```

There is still some metadata relating to the original function (`help(bar)` will still mention `foo`), but it doesn't affect functionality.

Another option is to use `lambda`s for one-liners:

```
foo = bar = baz = lambda: None
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, and it is even possible to store them in lists using loops. For instance:

```
l = []
for i in range(10):
    l.append(lambda: None)
```

And you can reference any of them through indices like `l[index]()`

For example:

```
c_events = 0
c_about = 1
l[c_events]()
```